# How to add dependentObservable to each item in observable Array?

Tags: knockout.js

I create observableArray from server data like this:

list: ko.observableArray(ko.mapping.fromJS(list))

how to add  dependentObservable to each item in array ? 
 Is it good way to createobservableArray ? i have problem with access to single element index

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation on controlling how objects are created by the mapping plugin here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#customizing_object_construction_using_create

You are able to pass mapping options to the mapping plugin that let you define how objects get created.  The documentation includes a sample where each item in an array gets a dependentObservable added.

Also, the mapping plugin will put your array into an observableArray automatically, so you don't need to wrap it again.

Here are a few samples:

- nested list with create callback using mapping in callback: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/badZb/
- list at root level with create callback using mapping in callback: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/badZb/1/
- list at root level with create callback use constructor function for object: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/badZb/2/